# Skip source checkout in specific pipeline phase

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I have a Azure Pipeline which consists of 2 phases. Phase 1 builds our solution and publishes the artifacts and phase 2 downloads these artifacts and runs our automatic tests on it.

As we are still stuck with a TFVC repository and therefore can't use YAML pipelines, I couldn't figure out, how to prevent phase 2 to checkout the sources in our classic (designer) pipeline.

I found out, that the following variables could do something like that, but I don't know how to set them up to just affect the **second** phase:

- `Agent.Source.Skip`
- `Build.SyncSources`

### UPDATE 1:

I tried to change the value of `Agent.Source.Skip` in phase 2 right before the checkout is done. Unfortunately the variable is readonly and can't be changed:
[image]

Thanks so much in advance for any help or input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `Agent.Source.Skip` from the variables tab and now the approach described in UPDATE 1 works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can split your build into two builds and use [build completion trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers-classic?view=azure-devops). Then use `Agent.Source.Skip` or `Build.SyncSources` on each build.

Comment: Thought already about that. As another workaround I could run the tests (second phase) in a release pipeline, but somehow I'm not very pleased with that approach. Actually I'm trying to merge 2 already existing pipelines into a single one.